# Commando gcc no Android Terminal Emulator

Tags: android, terminal

Estou à procura de uma IDE para meu celular e encontrei o Android Terminal Emulator. Porém, alguns commandos são diferentes. Gostaria de saber o comando para compilar no terminal. Por exemplo: o comando `gcc` nao existe no shell do celular.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa ser pelo terminal e precisa ser o GCC? Existem alternativas para compilar programas em C no Android tanto online quanto offline.
Uma busca rápida no Google me mostrou esse: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=name.antonsmirnov.android.cppdroid

Acredito que isso resolve o seu problema. Ir pela rota que você está indo vai dar mais trabalho do que vale a pena.

Comment: Obrigado eu vou tentar. Depois de tentar eu dou os resultados

Comment: Pablo eu ja usei o cppdroid não gostei ele buga muito

Comment: O que você quer dizer com bugar? Qual exatamente é o problema?

Comment: vc ta escrevendo e derepente da uma travadinha e apaga o codigo sem dizer q o espaço para propaganda é horrivel (propaganda nao é bug mas é um motivo XD).

Comment: outra coisa q esquici de falar muita coisa de C++11/14 não rola nesse cppdroid ele é muito desarualizado